# jQuery countdown timer - countdown to end of each month, starting first?

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

A client wants to have a countdown for his monthly sale, starting on the first of each month (server time = local time = time that should be used), and have it countdown till the end of the month (28 days 7 hours 6 minutes remaining). How would the logic behind this look like? Is there a library/plugin that does this by default?

Any pointers in the right direction would be amazing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must check this, I think it's what you need:

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

**UPDATE**

This is the code you need:

```
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var date = new Date();
                date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 1);
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: date});
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        Time left:
        <div id="defaultCountdown"/>        
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've seen this, but was unable to find what I was looking for. I've emailed the man behind this, and am eagerly awaiting his reply. edit: unless you've found what I was looking for of course ;)

Comment: Have you tried it? I've update my answer to show you how you can do what you need.